# Front-page.php stops working after contact form redirection

Tags: php, html, wordpress, contact-form

so I got hosting, installed wordpress on it, and I put my html on it, it contains contact form written in html and it has separate php file with process. Main file which is accessed when you come to website is "front-page.php" which gets elements and it works, but after I submit form, I redirects me to www.mywebsite.com/front-page.php instead of www.mywebsite.com and i get error in line 2 which worked before, it is line " , what should I do, how to fix this? Adding code

```js
<?php 

// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = $message_error = "";
$name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }
  
  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message_error = "Message is required";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }
  
  if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $message_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }
      
       $to = 'ignas.levinskas@mail.com';
      $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message)){
          echo("<script> window.location.href='../front-page.php'</script>");
          
          $name = $email = $message = '';
       
      }
        
  }
  
}


function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

```html
  <form id="contactform" method="post" action="http://li-designs.com/wp-content/themes/vcs-starter/assets/app.php" >
                    <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name"  required/> 
                        <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
                    <input name="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" required/>
                        <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
                    <textarea name="message" type="text" value="<?= $message ?>" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Message" ></textarea>
                        <span class="error"><?= $message_error ?></span>
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Send</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: remove **front-page.php** from this  line

 echo("<script> window.location.href='../front-page.php'</script>");

Comment: Redirects to folder, white page

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using header in the post method?

```
header('location': 'www.mywebsite.com');
```

In normal PHP it redirects you to that URL.

Comment: Was like that but with location in folder to front-page.php, if i put website like you suggested, I get error :/

Comment: What kind of error. Does the file exist and is the pathing right?